# Python 3.6: New line command '/n' is ignored when writing to a file on AWS Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I had searched but didn't find an answer that solved my problem...

I ran this code on pythob 3.6.5 on AWS Ubuntu:

```
from datetime import datetime

def log_to_txt(msg, filename='log_files/logcheck' + str(datetime.now().date()) + '.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        f.write(msg)
    f.close()

msg = 'hello\nworld'

log_to_txt(msg)
print(msg + '\nwas logged')
```

When I run the code in the console it works fine this is the output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-**** cta]$ python log_check.py
hello
world
was logged
```

but when i open the text file in NotePad it's just:

```
helloworld
```

Another thing I've notice is when I run the code on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.2 everything works great both the print to the console the the log.txt file

If someone can help I will be grateful!!

Thanks!

Comment: Notepad doesn't recognise `\n` as a line terminator, but only `\r\n`. Try a different editor (e.g. wordpad on windows).

Comment: Great!! works in word pad! Thank you very much! Such a stupid problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Notepad does not understand Unix LF line ending [until May 2018](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/). If you open the file in another text editor, for example Wordpad or better yet, a hex editor, you'll see that there's really a line break there (in a hex editor you'll see one `0A` byte).

If you print `\r\n` in Python then you'll be able to see the line break in Notepad.

Comment: great, another question: If i will change all the \n to \r\n it won't be visible as a chart in other programs like wordpad?

Comment: @Allon On Windows all programs should recognize CRLF ending, so Wordpad isn't going to break.

Comment: @Allon I'm unsure, but Vim in Terminal will show a `^M` at the end of every line, and `gedit` can handle it well. Anyway, on Ubuntu you have `dos2unix` this nice utility.

Comment: I will try ThanX!!